# Find elements of a list which are empty

Tags: list-manipulation

Sorry for the most basic of questions.  How would I find the positions of a list of elements which are empty, for example I have the list

```
a = {1, 2, {}, {}, 3, 5};
```

and I want to find the indices of the empty elements.

Comment: `Position[{1, 2, {}, {}, 3, 5}, {}]` yields `{{3}, {4}}`

Comment: Additionally you can get all elements of the list that are not `{}` using `Cases[{1, 2, {}, {}, 3, 5}, Except[{}]]`.

Comment: This is better `DeleteCases[{1, 2, {}, {}, 3, 5}, {}]`.

Comment: @Artes I would say its equivalent.

Comment: @mmal It is not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to find the position of something in a given expression, you should use [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v4-zh/Built-inFunctions/ListsAndMatrices/ListTesting/FreeQ.html).

In this example, you could simply write:

```
Position[{1, 2, {}, {}, 3, 5}, {}]
(*{{3}, {4}}*)
```

I have to mention that this not the whole power of `Position`: the second parameter of `Position` can be a "pattern"(which may be not known by a matlab coder:)), look up the [doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Patterns.html) for more imformation.

Comment: Great thanks, I know a little about regexp

Comment: @mor22 a [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pattern.html) in _Mathematica_ is different from a regular expression. They're similar in some respects, but a pattern is more broad.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks, I'm still learning!

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. In some cases, i.e. when importing data, one might need to use {""} instead of {}.